# barcodes formats supported by ZXing

Tags: format, barcode, zxing

Please advice what are the 1D barcodes and QR code formats supported by ZXing

List of barcodes format supported.

Answer (score 2):

ZXing can support this formats of 1D and 2D barcodes :

- UPC-A and UPC-E
- EAN-8 and EAN-13
- Code 39
- Code 93
- Code 128
- ITF
- Codabar
- RSS-14 (all variants)
- RSS Expanded (most variants)
- QR Code
- Data Matrix
- Aztec ('beta' quality)
- PDF 417 ('alpha' quality)
- MaxiCode

Comment: Thanks for the information .. how about QR code format

Comment: @PatmawathyPatma I think you're thinking about 2D bar code when you talk about QR Code...

Comment: @PatmawathyPatma. QRCode, Data Matrix, Aztec, PDF 417 and MaxiCode all are 2D barcodes